# Is there a clean way to remove the common ruby object initialization code?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there a clean way to iterate over the attr_reader attributes and set them?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar, :baz, ...

  def initialize attrs
    @bar = attrs[:bar]
    @baz = attrs[:baz]
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Why do you want to assign `attr[:bar]`  to `@foo` and `attr[:baz]` to `@bar`?

Comment: @Stefan - You're right. It should be `@bar = attrs[:bar]`. I'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hash keys matches the attribute name, one possibility is to inherit a struct:

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:bar, :baz, keyword_init: true) # Note the "keyword_init" parameter
end

puts Foo.new(bar: 42, baz: :foo).bar
# => 42
```

Struct will also create public writers, so if you want them not to be public you have to set them private

```
FOO_ATTRS = [:bar, :baz]
class Foo < Struct.new(*FOO_ATTRS, keyword_init: true) # Note the "keyword_init" parameter
  # Make method 'my_attribute=' private if needed
  private *FOO_ATTRS.map { |attr| "#{attr}=" }
end

puts Foo.new(bar: 42, baz: :foo).bar
```

If you want to rename hash keys for a different attribute name:

```
class Foo
  INITIAL_ATTRS = {
   foo: :@bar,
   bar: :@baz
  }

  attr_reader *(INITIAL_ATTRS.values.map { |k| k.to_s.delete('@').to_sym })

  def initialize attrs
    attrs.slice(*INITIAL_ATTRS.keys).each do |var, value|
      instance_variable_set(INITIAL_ATTRS[var], value)
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT

Another possibility is to use private attr_writer so you don't have to deal with @ tricks

```
class Foo
  INITIAL_ATTRS = {
   foo: :bar,
   bar: :baz
  }

  attr_reader *(INITIAL_ATTRS.values)

  def initialize attrs
    attrs.slice(*INITIAL_ATTRS.keys).each do |var, value|
      send("#{INITIAL_ATTRS[var]}=", value)
    end
  end

  private

   attr_writer *(INITIAL_ATTRS.values)
end
```

Note that if you don't want to translate foo to bar you can use an array instead of a hash for INITIAL_ATTRS. This would simplify the code by removing `.values` and `.keys`

```
class Foo
  INITIAL_ATTRS = [:foo, :bar]

  attr_reader *INITIAL_ATTRS

  def initialize attrs
    attrs.slice(*INITIAL_ATTRS).each do |var, value|
      send("#{var}=", value)
    end
  end

  private

   attr_writer *INITIAL_ATTRS
end
```

Comment: `self.` is superfluous and `instance_variable_set` requires a valid instance variable name, i.e. `:@bar` works, but `:bar` doesn't. You have to convert the keys accordingly.

Comment: Also added a 2nd (cleaner imo) solution, that doesn't require any @ nor string/symbol conversion

Comment: Your solution works. But compared to some `@bar = attr[:bar]` lines the refactored class is much more complex now and somehow looks _less_ clean to me. You should probably extract the whole logic into a module, which would also make it reusable.

Comment: That's why I think `@foo = attr[:bar]` in the author post in fact means `@foo = attr[:foo]` and why I previously added a 2 lines only solution for this use case (inheriting a Struct). For the solutions I proposed with a key renaming yes it's more complex (and yes, should be moved into module) but all depends on what the goal is. It's different if you want to make sure you have no difference between your attrs in initialize and in attr_reader, how many attributes you have, if there are other attributes that should not be initializable this way, etc...

Comment: @firetonton - Yes, you are correct. I meant `@bar = attr[:bar]`. BTW, how did you learn these Ruby details?

Comment: A third option would be to capture the desired attributes in a single Hash e.g. `@attr` and read through this Hash. This is how rails deals with its Model attributes. By way of example `INITIAL_ATTRS.each {|attr| define_method(attr) { @attr[attr] }}` and `def initialize(attr); @attr = attr.slice(*INITIAL_ATTR); end`

Comment: @BSeven So did the proposal with Struct solved your problem ? (I updated it in case you want not to have attributes writer methods) For you other question, I work with ruby for many years now so I've written/read a lot of code. Blog articles, ruby weekly news and youtube conferences (railsconf, rubykaigi, etc...) are great resources to discover various aspects of the language.